# Should we enforce a "movie" tag on questions about The Hobbit movie?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

There seems to be a bunch of Qs related to The Hobbit movie in 2012 - many of which have nothing to do with the book (e.g. [How were Gandalf, Elrond and Galadriel able to comunicate telepathically?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/29142/how-were-gandalf-elrond-and-galadriel-able-to-comunicate-telepathically) )

Should we enforce (via edits) that they are tagged with [movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie) to avoid confusion?

Comment: Yes, definitely. I heartily support this suggestion.

Comment: Although I'm not opposed to making a distinction like that, I think "enforcing" is going a bit too far. What about questions that sound like they're referring to the book, but can also be answered with information from the movie? Tagging them with "book" might push away people who've only seen the movie.

Comment: @MrLister - This question was very clearly about a movie, both from the name of the work and mentioning plot elements NOT in a book

Comment: I'm pretty sure Gandalf, Elrond, and Galadriel's telepathic communication was somewhere in the books, though I don't recall where.

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: I think it is good in a way; but considering that most people who ask the questions after having seen the movie don't realise that there is such a **huge** discrepancy; Having the 'movie' tag could cause potential answerers to *think* that the answers should only be from the movie canon.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As the movie contains elements that don't appear in the books, I think that, yes, we absolutely should enforce such a requirement (tagging with [movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie)).

Comment: Has the movie tag been consistently enforced on LOTR questions?

Comment: @TGnat the differences in LotR are nothing compared to those in the Hobbit...

Answer (score 1):

I disagree. What would be the point? It won't help searching and filtering unless we can specify "answers with tag [hobbit] but not [movie]", which I think we can't (but correct me if I'm wrong!).

Answers which tell us that some detail is from the book but not from the movie, or viceversa, are entertaining and informative anyway.

Comment: You can [search for `[the-hobbit] -[movie]`](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings+-movie).

Comment: @Gilles Great! I didn't know that.