# When should we go to the [movie]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

The description for the tag [movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie) is as follows:

> Use this tag when specifying the question is about the movie version or adaptation of a story.

This raises a couple questions:

1. Could this imply that the OP is looking for answers specific to the movie version of a work, and thus unintentionally turning away possible answers from other versions, even when the **question itself** does not specify which sources to use? Since wikis are [written for the site's audience](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1627/75000), it seems we'd want everyone to know exactly what they're looking for.
2. [This answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2555/75000) mentions that, because the different versions contain different elements, that tagging with [movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie) makes sense, but what if the question is about something they all share? Is it still appropriate to use this tag because the OP's question **stemmed** from something they saw while watching the movie?

Since I'm the one with the confusion, my suggestions would be that we either reword the wiki to **specifically** allow answers from other versions, or create a new tag (dibs) that can be used when the OP only wants answers based on the movie(s), such as [movie-specific](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie-specific) or something along those lines.

An example of a reworked wiki could be:

> Use this tag when specifying the question is about the movie version or adaptation of a story. This tag does not disallow answers from the books, video games, or other versions of the story.

So far the normal thing to do when you only want answers about a specific universe is to state them in your question, and rewording the current wiki will allow that to continue. If we make the new tag, we might also want to make new ones (dibs) for [book-specific](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-specific) and [game-specific](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-specific) so all the generic bases are covered, similar to how [star-wars-legends](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-legends) works for specifying canon.

So what are our thoughts on this?

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that `movie` also gets used to narrow `story-identification` questions.

Comment: You should really have put your reworked wiki in the Answer section and not in the question section. The Question section should be you asking a question and the Answer section should contain the part that ends "your thoughts on this?" with which we respond with upvotes.

Comment: This is a bigger thing than movie. See `books` and `comics`

Comment: @Edlothiad I've seen others put their suggested fixes in their question before, possibly since it's not *really* an answer? Anyway, that's how I assumed things were done.

Comment: I know, they're all wrong. I mean you pose a question? You pose a solution and then you pose a "what do you think?" Question which isn't really a question it's just there to turn the answer into your question into a question. I'm not slating your Question (& Answer) but the way the frequency of this needs to stop, the question section needs to be questions, and any solutions need to go into the answers, otherwise the answers just a "yes this is good" or "no this is bad" these aren't answers with solution, they're a poll. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Edlothiad I think so. You should make a new meta to talk about that so we have something to link to in the future.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd The funny thing is, I can think of any other way to word it then as a non-meta, a question suggestion pair?

Comment: @Edlothiad You mentioned *polls*. Maybe we should suggest that feature for Meta?

Comment: Given the +6/-0 score on my answer, I've gone ahead and made that the tag wiki excerpt for [tag:movie].

Answer (score 3):

Here's a suggestion to be voted on.

> This tag has three different uses: for questions specifically about the movie version of a work which has been adapted for different media (answers may draw on any adaptation but must be relevant to the question); for questions seeking identification of a movie (use together with the [story-identification] tag); or for wider genre questions about movies as a whole (generally together with the [history-of] tag).

*Alas for the lack of markdown in tag wiki excerpts ...*

I haven't checked whether this text is too long for the character limit on excerpts. If so, we can put some of the text in parentheses into the main tag wiki instead (although bearing in mind that even fewer people read the tag wiki than the excerpt). Some kind of warning about the third category, to avoid people asking overly broad questions, might also be nice, but it would probably have to go in the main wiki rather than the excerpt, due to that character limit.

Comment: My brain isn't working right to turn this into a concise answer, but we have separate tags for books between "the book version" and "this is about a book". Would it make sense to do the same with films?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots do we? Some are for the films (such as the individual tolkien ones) and not for the books.

Comment: @Edlothiad: Effectively, we use `books` for the former and `novel` for the later, although arguably the latter is only a subset of books.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Oooooh I get your comment now. `Books` is for your former... I get it. What would it be for movies? `film` for film version and `movie` for identification

Comment: Yes. I think that's exactly what I said. :-D

Comment: @FuzzyBoots your brain clearly isn't the only one working right, I was translating your puzzle into simple english

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Wait, what? As far as I know, the only difference between the [tag:books] and [tag:novel] tags is that one applies to all books and the other only to novels.

Comment: @Edlothiad Don't you mean "clearly isn't the only one **not** working right"? :-D

Comment: @Randal'Thor: "Use this tag to indicate the question is about the book version or adaptation of a work. If applicable, use a more specific tag instead (novel, short-stories, comics). For differences between the book and other versions, such as a movie, use "adaptation-comparison"." So yes, it looks like the intent is for "the book version of" rather than "about a book".

Comment: @FuzzyBoots But what about actual usage, rather than the tag wiki which hardly anyone reads? AFAIK, both [tag:books] and [tag:novel] are used in much the same way as [tag:movie]: both for ID questions and to specify a particular medium for something with multiple adaptations. None of the medium tags are used for just any question "about a [book|movie|etc.]", except for ID questions.

Comment: @Randal'Thor you're correct, we only add novel in practice if the user specifies a novel

Comment: In theory, for a work with 2 media versions using the same tag (a poor practice, but unfortunately the likes of Harry Potter means it's probably never going away), you _can_ use `book` to clarify that you're only asking about the books, not the movies. And it _has_ been used that way, but generally it's more obvious with something like `spider-man` + `comics` where you're only after comic answers, not movie. The best guideline, though, is to create a tag for each specific work, so `the-martian` should really have `the-martian` and `the-martian-2015`. Instead, we see `the-martian` + `movie`

Comment: Which means, _how_ we use `movie` and `book` is inconsistent, because why aren't the rest of the questions about `the-martian` also tagged with `book`? And that's just one recent example.

Comment: "This tag has three different uses" Shouldn't we immediately differentiate between those uses by using different tags?